# Swift: Using core data with tabbed based application error: 'Cannot create an NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a nil model'

Tags: core-data, swift

I'm trying to use Core Data in a tabbed based application. But when I try to save something it gives the following error:

> 'Cannot create an NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a nil model'

This is my app delegate:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary!) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication!) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication!) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication!) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication!) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication!) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

// MARK: - Core Data stack

lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
    // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "Coders.test" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
    let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    return urls[urls.count-1] as NSURL
    }()

lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("test", withExtension: "momd")
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)
    }()

lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    // Create the coordinator and store
    var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("test.sqlite")
    var error: NSError? = nil
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    if coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil, error: &error) == nil {
        coordinator = nil
        // Report any error we got.
        let dict = NSMutableDictionary()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
        error = NSError.errorWithDomain("YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }

    return coordinator
    }()

lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    if !coordinator {
        return nil
    }
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
    }()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext () {
    if let moc = self.managedObjectContext {
        var error: NSError? = nil
        if moc.hasChanges && !moc.save(&error) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }
}
```

My function to save the data:

```
func calculate(maand: UITextField!, urenGewerkt: UITextField!, uurloon: UITextField!) {
    NSLog("\(maand.text)")
    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    let en = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Loon", inManagedObjectContext: context)

    //Create instance of pur data model and initialize
    var newItem = dataHandlingClass(entity: en, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)

    if maand.text.isEmpty && urenGewerkt.text.isEmpty && uurloon.text.isEmpty {
        NSLog("Empty")
    } else {
        newItem.maand = maand!.text
        newItem.uurGewerkert = urenGewerkt!.text
        newItem.uurLoon = uurloon!.text

        var error: NSError?

        context.save(&error)
    }


}
```

Datahandling class:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class dataHandlingClass : NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var maand: String!
    @NSManaged var uurLoon: String!
    @NSManaged var uurGewerkert: String!
}
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this error?

I saw some related questions about this, but I could'nt get the answer I needed.

Comment: Do you have a test.xcdatamodel file in your project? And it is added to Compile sources?

Comment: I have a .xcdatamodel file yes, but where do I need to add this?

Comment: Go to targets, select your target, open Build Phases tab and check Compile Sources section. test.xcdatamodel must be in the list.

Comment: Okay, my .xcdatamodel file is in there

Comment: Just to be sure that we've eliminated any slips: your model file name is `test` all lower case letters?

Comment: Yes that's the name of my filename

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `.xcdatamodel` instead of `.scdatamodeld` you should build model bundle URL in the following way:

```
let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("test", withExtension: "mom") // not momd!
```

Comment: Doesn't change anything, I still get the same error :-(

Comment: Lets check if your NSBundle has any *.momd or *.mom files in it. Here is the gist with code that writes to the log all model files that you have in your bundle: https://gist.github.com/keenle/f0cb41b290cc3088f19b. Put code in `application(application:, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:)`. Lets see if required model exists in the bundle.